# Application at context path / could not be started - Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, tomcat8

I have problem with Tomcat 8, my deployed application doesn't start. It works on Eclipse Luna, but Jenkins has problems. I have no idea how fix it.

Jenkins console output:
http://pastebin.com/eki2mUBQ

/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/logs/catalina.out:
http://pastebin.com/YD4sy290

Ubuntu 14.04 
Jenskin 1.614

Answer (score 0):

After going through your log, I found:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

This error is reported when the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of `slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar` on the class path should solve the problem.
SINCE 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.
You can download SLF4J bindings from the project [Download Page](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Comment: I have this dependencies in maven, it doesn't help:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.12</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.12</version>
  </dependency>